# After update, calculator program is now called unnamed

Tags: icons

After a regular software update, the program previously called "Calculator" is now called "Unnamed".

In the applications menu, the icon is still correct, but the program is now called unnamed.

In the launch panel, the icon is now the default gear icon, rather than the calculator icon.

Clicking on any of them still opens the calculator program though.

Has anyone else seem this problem or know of a way to correct it?

I am using elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit)

Comment: I added a answer. Mark it as answer if it works

Comment: You really, really should not be running the daily PPA. It is unstable and you're going to encounter problems like this while running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following command to open the calculator entry in Scratch

```
sudo -i scratch-text-editor /usr/share/applications/pantheon-calculator.desktop
```

Change the text after line that starts with **Name=** (it should currently be unnamed or something , if the line isn't there add it) to **Calculator**.

Or replace the contents of the file with (from my laptop)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.1
Name=Calculator
Comment=Calculate in an elementary way.
Exec=pantheon-calculator %U
Icon=accessories-calculator
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;Utility;Office;
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=pantheon-calculator

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=AboutDialog

[AboutDialog Shortcut Group]
Name=About Calculator
Exec=pantheon-calculator --about
```

Comment: Just looked at my system (had the same problem).  For some reason the entries "Name=Calculator", "Comment=..." and "Name=About Calculator" were instead "_Name=Calculator", "_Comment=..." and "_Name=...".  Removing the underscores fixed the problem.

Comment: @TimothyGray Can you mark this as answer since it worked

Comment: I'm not the original poster, so I don't think so

Comment: This answer and the comment from Timothy Gray fixed it for me. Thanks.